# Inject/inserting the values directly on the view MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC, and have a MVC 4 web application and I retrieve a collection of items in the application start(static reference data). I want to display this collection of items when my view loads and loop through it creating links on view, I want to use javascript to inject this information. I found a post where they mention doing it in the view like this

```
<script type="text/javascript> 
 <%= Model.JavascriptToInsert %> 
</script>
```

but I am looking for a working example of implementing this approach. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should serialize your collection to json before you put it to your page.

**Use ViewBag to show the data**

Controller:

```
    //Show data with ViewBag
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.DataList = SomeClass.SomeStaticList;
        return View();
    }
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list = <%=Json.Encode(ViewBag.DataList)%>;

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        //do something with your data
    }
</script>
```

**Use strongly-typed view**

Controller:

```
    //Show data with ViewModel
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new TempProject.Models.SampleModel();
        model.ListData = SomeClass.SomeStaticList;
        return View(model);
    }
```

View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<TempProject.Models.SampleModel>" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var list = <%=Json.Encode(Model.ListData) %>;

    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        //do something with your data
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @Charlie: Do you have to do anything special to get MVC 4 to accept the old MVC syntax? I get a compile error with your example.

Comment: @HiTech Magic: MVC4 support both aspx and cshtml as it's view engine, and the question is asking with aspx

Comment: @Charlie: That makes more sense. I shall retract my previous comment.